# Help solving autonomous, non-linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Apologies if this is a very basic question - it's many years since I've done any calculus.

I have a differential equation of the form

$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} = e^{-y(t)} - 1 - y(t)$$

I think this has an exact solution, which I'd like to find. My reading this morning suggests this is an autonomous non-linear ODE and that my strategy to solve it should involve making some kind of variable substitution to transform it into a linear problem, which I can then try and solve.

**Is this approach correct** and, if so, could anyone point me in the right direction regarding **what substitution to use** and how to proceed, please?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure it will help, but if $y(t)$ is near of $1$, then $e^{-y(t)}\approx 1-y(t)$ and thus your equation become $y'(t)=-2y(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=0$ is a stationary solution.

It is an equation in separated variables. The general solution is
$$
\int\frac{dy}{e^{-y}-1-y}=t+C.
$$
Unfortunately I do not think there is a closed form solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Thanks @Julián. Based on a recent conversation I was under the impression that a closed form solution does exist, but as I am not familiar with this subject it's possible I just misunderstood what I was being told. I am very grateful for your reply, as without it I would likely have spent the rest of my week getting frustrated by my inability to do basic integration!

Comment: _Mathematica_ does not give a closed form solution.